# cant get the value of textbox and put i into a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textbox

I set the value of the textbox in Page-load and assign it into a variable in the java script. but this line wont execute.

```
        y = document.getElementByID("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").value;
```

it wont work either when I set value of textbox in the aspx page.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 TextBox1.Text = "14";
 }
```

and

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="14"></asp:TextBox>
```

neither of them worked
                        -------- here is the script -----

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
                                var map;
                                var y;
                    y = document.getElementByID("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").value;
                    y = parseInt(y);

                require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function (Map) {

                    esriConfig.defaults.map.panDuration = 1;   

                        var map = new Map("map", {
                        center: [-118, y],
                        zoom: 15,
                        basemap: "satellite"

                    });
                });
            </script>
```

what am i doing wrong? Everything works OK when I just assign y to a number , Is this even a good practice to get values from asp controls?

Comment: How do you set the value of textbox?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "14";

        } and <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="14"></asp:TextBox> neither of them worked

Comment: Please update the question with this code, Its not readable here.

Answer (score 2):

```
"<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>"
```

This is not getting evaluated like you think, it will just send this as a literal string to the client. Instead you should do:

```
y = document.getElementByID("'" + <%= TextBox1.ClientID %> "'").value;
```

Even so, this is quite ugly code. Since the textbox does not seem to be a dynamically generated contol, you should set it's `ClientIDMode` property to `Static` or `Predictable`. Then hard-code the ID in your javascript.

Comment: @arvin can you check your console in browser for javascript errors? Have you checked what you receive exactly from the server? I can't just guess what's wrong, "it didn't work" is extremely vague.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list---line 53-- this is the line 53
 y = document.getElementByID("'" + TextBox1 "'").value;

Comment: I get TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null When i use this line:
y = document.getElementByID("'" + <%= TextBox1.ClientID %> + "'").value;